# How to group by a column and count the number of categories in other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
    name        tags
0   abc (1990)  AB|A|BC
1   def (2000)  BC|AB
2   yz (1990)   A|AB
```

The values in `tags` column are pipe-separated. Further, the format of the values in column `name` is like `description (year)`. I want to count the number of tags for each year to get a `Series` object like this:

```
year    
1990  A     2
      AB    2
      BC    1
2000  AB    1
      BC    1
```

Or its equivalent as a `DataFrame`:

```
    year    tags    count
0   1990    A       2
1   1990    AB      2
2   1990    BC      1
3   2000    AB      1
4   2000    BC      1
```

I have a solution for this however since it involves defining a custom function to pass to `apply` method, I was wondering whether more compact or efficient solution exists?

Here is my current solution:

```
years = df['name'].str.slice(start=-5, stop=-1).rename('year')
new_df = df['tags'].str.split('|', expand=True).join(years)

def count_tags(g):
    return g.drop(columns=['year']).stack().value_counts()

new_df.groupby('year').apply(count_tags)
```

which gives:

```
year    
1990  A     2
      AB    2
      BC    1
2000  AB    1
      BC    1
dtype: int64
```

**P.S.** It does not matter for me whether the `year` is stored as string or integer in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
new_df = (df.assign(year=lambda x: x['name'].str[-5:-1])
            .set_index('year')['tags']
            .str.split('|', expand=True)
            .stack()
            .reset_index(name='tags')
            .groupby(['year','tags'])
            .size()
            .reset_index(name='count'))
print (new_df)

   year tags  count
0  1990    A      2
1  1990   AB      2
2  1990   BC      1
3  2000   AB      1
4  2000   BC      1
```

**Explanation**:

1. For one line solution first use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new column with slicing
2. For index by `year` use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
3. Then [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for DataFrame and reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` with `MultiIndex`
4. For columns from MultiIndex add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html)
5. Last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for column `count`

Another solution:

```
from itertools import chain

tags = df['tags'].str.split('|')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'tags' : list(chain.from_iterable(tags.values.tolist())), 
    'year' : df['name'].str[-5:-1].repeat(tags.str.len())
})

print (df1)
  tags  year
0   AB  1990
1    A  1990
2   BC  1990
3   BC  2000
4   AB  2000
5    A  1990
6   AB  1990

df2 = df1.groupby(['year','tags']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df2)
   year tags  count
0  1990    A      2
1  1990   AB      2
2  1990   BC      1
3  2000   AB      1
4  2000   BC      1
```

**Explanation**:

1. Create lists by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)
2. Get lengths of lists by [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html)
3. Last [`repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.repeat.html) columns and flattening
4. [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `size`

Comment: Thanks for the nice solutions and the explanation. I learned a lot from them. Any idea which one might be more efficient?

Comment: @today - I think second one.